# Calculating distance to the coastline in R -Cyprus example

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sp

I have a `data.frame`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(geosphere)
library(osmdata)
library(rgeos)
library(readxl)
library(writexl)

d1 <- data_frame(
  title = c("base1", "base2", "base3", "base4"),
  lat = c(34.7453751328344, 34.721682790624, 34.7605669404291, 34.7542187),
  long = c(33.3424447992104, 33.3282082548538, 33.4176870768428, 33.4173241))

d1 = data.frame(d1) 
colnames(d1)= c("title","lat","long") 
# convert to sf object 

d1_sf <- d1 %>% st_as_sf(coords = c('long','lat')) %>% st_set_crs(4326) 

osm_box <- getbb (place_name = "Cyprus") %>% opq () %>% add_osm_feature("natural", "coastline") %>% osmdata_sf() 

dist <- geosphere::dist2Line(p = st_coordinates(d1_sf), line = st_coordinates(osm_box$osm_lines)[,1:2]) 

df <- cbind( d1 %>% rename(y=lat,x=long),dist) %>% mutate(miles=distance/1609)
```

I attempted to use the method found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51837454/r-measuring-distance-from-a-coastline), but I am getting incorrect results.

Can someone assist?

Comment: I get incorrect results when I manually check my data . I used this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51837454/r-measuring-distance-from-a-coastline

Comment: Hi Themis, please provide the code you are using thus far that resulted in your incorrect results. As it is, we have no idea what coastline data you downloaded.